# Is this method BigO(n^2) or BigO(nLog(n))?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

This is a method i wrote that checks if two strings are premutations of each other:

```
public static boolean permutation(String str1, String str2) {

boolean terminate = false;

for(int x = 0; x < str1.length(); x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < str2.length(); y++){
        if(y != str2.length() - 1){
            if(str1.charAt(x) == str2.charAt(y)){
                str1.replace(String.valueOf(str1.charAt(x)), "");
                str2.replace(String.valueOf(str2.charAt(y)), "");
                break;
            }
            
        }else{
            if(str1.charAt(x) != str2.charAt(y)){
                return false;
            }else{
                str1.replace(String.valueOf(str1.charAt(x)), "");
                str2.replace(String.valueOf(str2.charAt(y)), "");
            }
            
        }
        
    }
    
}

return true;

}
```

as you see in the code I'm using a for loop inside another for loop but not checking all the elements of x with y (but sometimes checking all the elements of y with the current value of x), So I'm guessing is BigO(nLog(n)) since we are not comparing all the elements overall but my mind is telling me this might be BigO(n^2). Also I am removing the indexes once a certain condition is met so the other  remained indexes Won't inspect the removing elements, in my opinion it is a BigO(nLog(n)) but just in case it is not i want to know why.

!UPDATE!: Due to the lack of knowledge and that i did that algorithm in 7 minutes  the actual problem was an O(n^3), I did not pay attention to the replace method of the string that it was actually an O(n) time complexity, also did not check if the input where the same length so it returned true when it should return false in some cases, here's the new code judging by it's structure i would say it is a O(n) in it's best and O(n^2) in it's worst:

```
    public static boolean permutation(String str1, String str2){
    
    if(str1.length() != str2.length()){
        return false;
    }
    
    
    
    HashSet<Character> string1 = new HashSet<>();

    
    
    for(int x =0; x < str1.length(); x++){
        string1.add(str1.charAt(x));
    }
    
    for(int x = 0; x < str1.length(); x++){
        if(!string1.contains(str2.charAt(x))){
            return false;
        }
    }
    
    
    return true;
}
```

Comment: due to the `replace` it looks more like O(n^3).

Comment: The `replace` lines here do nothing because you don't assign the result anywhere, and strings are immutable. I am unconvinced that your algorithm actually does what you say it does, and there is no sense analysing how efficiently it gives wrong answers.

Comment: @kaya3, I think the `replace` will anyway take O(N) for comparison.

Comment: For example, your method has `permutation("a", "ab")` and `permutation("aab", "abb")` both returning `true` where the correct results should be `false`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't considered the time complexity for the `replace()` method. It takes O(N) time complexity.

Agreed that you are processing the strings depending upon certain conditions, but the 2 `for` loops anyway make the time complexity O(N^2).

Therefore, overall time complexity = O(N^2 * N) = O(N^3).

To be precise,  if the length of `str1` is **N** and the length of `str2` is **M**, then the time complexity ~ O (N * M * (N + M)).

Comment: This is missing that the `replace` method is only called O(1) times per iteration of the outer loop, due to the `break` statement and the check on the index `y`.